# What is the dimension of the vector space $\{a+b\sqrt{3} ; a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ over rational numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I proved that this set is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. But I have no idea about the dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Can you find one basis for the vector space? Take any element as a starting point of the basis and see which element you can't write as a linear combination of it. Then if there's such add it into the basis. If there isn't you've got yourself a basis. Repeat this until you find a basis.

Then the dimension is a the number of elements in the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Can we have $a+b\sqrt3=0$ with $a\neq0$ or $b\neq0$? No, bacause

- if $b=0$, then, since $a+b\sqrt3=0$, $a=0$;
- if $b\neq0$, then $\sqrt3=-\frac ba\in\mathbb Q$, which is impossible.

Therefore, $1$ and $\sqrt3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Since they generate your vector space, they form a basis of it. So, the dimension is $2$.

Comment: Why do you answer a question that you put on hold yourself?

Comment: @Math_QED I decided to answer it in spite of thinking that the OP should have put more effort into it. Do you see a contradiction here? (This is *not* a rethorical question.)

Comment: I actually do. Putting it on hold gives a signal to the OP that tells him he must change something in his post. On the other hand, he receives (quality) answers that perfectly adress his question, so why should he change something?

Comment: @Math_QED I guess you are right.

Comment: Don't understand me wrong. I think you are doing a great job on the site, but I feel like encouraging this kind of posts is just not the way to go. A hint is more than enough imo.

Comment: @Math_QED I will follow your suggestion from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$a+b\sqrt{3} = a(1,0)+b\sqrt{3}(0,1)$

(1,0), (0,1) span given vector space. Further (1,0), (0,1) are linearly independent and so they form basis. thus dimension = 2

Comment: Would you like to elaborate what $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ mean? After all we're not working $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, so no need of two coordinates.

Comment: What is wrong this? i did not understand. Field(subfield) is vector space. Complex numbers(Rational numbers), QXQ(Q) are all vector spaces. Take any point in form $a+b \sqrt{3} $ and express it as span of vectors in QXQ or C which is complex numbers. If span of these vectors is linearly independent it forms basis.

Comment: Yeah they are vector space, but the vector space in our question is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$, so there aren't any coordinates. It's true that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}] \cong \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, but it's doens't make things simpler. As I've said we're working in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$, so the elements are $a + b\sqrt{3}$, not $(a,b)$, like in $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Stefan4024 got it. I understood now. thanks for pointing it.